# Django: The value of the id field is coming None

Tags: django, django-models

I want to create a unique id for all my groups in my django project which will help us to easily detect the user action.

I have tried the following:

Models:

```
class Group1(models.Model):
    urlhash = models.CharField(max_length=6, null=True, blank=True, unique=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True,blank=True)
    group_name = models.CharField(max_length=32)
```

This is the functionality I have given:

```
def save(self):
    if not self.urlhash:
       if self.user.profile.user_type == 'Business User':
           self.urlhash = 'B' + str(self.user.id) + ('00') + str(self.id)
       else:
           self.urlhash = 'P' + str(self.user.id) + ('00') + str(self.id)
super(Group1, self).save()
```

But `str(self.id)` is coming None.

Can anyone plz explain me why this error is happening?

Thank you

**According to the solution given by @JPG and @sandip I finally got the solution**

```
def save(self):
   super(Group1, self).save()
   if not self.urlhash:
       if self.user.profile.user_type == 'Business User':
           self.urlhash = 'B' + str(self.user.id) + ('00') + str(self.id)
           Group1.objects.filter(pk=self.pk).update(urlhash=self.urlhash)
       else:
           self.urlhash = 'P' + str(self.user.id) + ('00') + str(self.id)
           Group1.objects.filter(pk=self.pk).update(urlhash=self.urlhash)
```

This works for me...Thank you everyone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the `id` you need to try the answer provided by @JPG. But since the `save()` method is being called in initial step, the urlhash might not get updated as it is not saved in the instance. To update the `urlhash`, you can do something like:

```
def save(self):
    super(Group1, self).save()
    if not self.urlhash:
        if self.user.profile.user_type == 'Business User':
            urlhash = 'B' + str(self.User.id) + ('00') + str(self.id)
            Group1.objects.filter(pk=self.pk).update(urlhash=urlhash)
        else:
            self.urlhash = 'P' + str(self.User.id) + ('00') + str(self.id)
            Group1.objects.filter(pk=self.pk).update(urlhash=urlhash)
```

Comment: This would probably raise an error because you should;d have use **`filter()`** instead of **`get()`** method

Comment: @JPG thanks for the suggestion. I have edited my answer

Answer (score 7):

Why **`self.id`** is **`None`**?

This is because Django assigns the **`id`**/**`pk`** values after the object creation, that is after calling the **`save()`** method of model.

So, call the **`save()`** method and then try to do your logic, as below

```
def save(self):
    super(Group1, self).save()
    if not self.urlhash:
        if self.user.profile.user_type == 'Business User':
            self.urlhash = 'B' + str(self.User.id) + ('00') + str(self.id)
            <b>self.__class__.objects.filter.(pk=self.pk).update(urlhash=urlhash)</b>
        else:
            self.urlhash = 'P' + str(self.User.id) + ('00') + str(self.id)
            <b>self.__class__.objects.filter.(pk=self.pk).update(urlhash=urlhash)
```

**UPDATE**
I for got one point that the instance should be again updated after calling the the **`save()`** method. So I had used the statement

```
self.__class__.objects.filter.(pk=self.pk).update(urlhash=urlhash)
```

Thanks to [@sanip](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9744320/sanip) for the idea got from his answer

Comment: Yeah tried this...But it doesnot update the `urlhash ` whenever a `Group1` object is created or updated.

Comment: Check whether the instance having `urlhash` value in it

Comment: @NiladryKar Now I found the problem in my answer and corrected it :)

Comment: Yeah just chek my updated question...I just changed `self.__class__` to Group1.And it worked